# Number theory on square numbers

Tags: number-theory

Can a square number be split as the sum of two other squares in two different ways?
The Pythagorean numbers help us to identify numbers which can be split as sum of two squares. Is this unique?

Comment: [Number of integer solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/number-of-integer-solutions-of-x2-y2-k) gives all the information you need. And then some. Voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

By the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), which states that $$(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2 = (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2$$ you can get a number which is a sum of two squares two different ways by multiplying two sums of two squares.

So from two Pythagorean triples $a^2 + b^2 = a_1^2$ and $c^2 + d^2 = a_2^2$ , the left hand side simplifies to $(a_1a_2)^2$, you can get a number that can be written as a sum of two squares.

Comment: Love whipping out the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012733/prove-that-a-positive-polynomial-function-can-be-written-as-the-squares-of-two-p/1012765#1012765

Comment: Of course if you have $a^2 + b^2 = a_1^2$ and $c^2 + d^2 = a_2^2$ then you also have $(a_2a)^2 + (a_2b)^2 = (a_1a_2)^2$ and $(a_1c)^2 + (a_1d)^2 = (a_1a_2)^2.$ This is how $65^2$ comes to be the sum of two squares in four different ways: take $a=4,b=3,c=12,d=5.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$3,4,5$ is a PPT, meaning that any multiple (like $6,8,10$) is a PT

$5,12,13$ is a PPT as well ...

Comment: Why the downvote? Not a good hint?

Answer (score 0):

For example
\begin{eqnarray*}
65^2=63^2+16^2=33^2+56^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: In fact this happens infinitely often, see [this sequence of the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A024508).

Comment: In addition, there are the obvious $65^2=26^2+52^2=25^2+60^2$ (multiples of $3,4,5$ and $5,12,13$). So that's not just two, but four ways for $65^2.$

Comment: @BrianHopkins Most of the numbers in that list are not squares, but of course some are.

Comment: @DavidK Oops, yes: of the many related sequences, I think [A009177](http://oeis.org/A009177) is more relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and illuminating discussion